# Change Password Programmatically

Tags: linux, scripting, password, raspbian

In the current version of Raspian, I know it is possible to change the password of the current logged in user from the command line like so:

```
sudo passwd
```

which will then prompt the user to enter a new password twice. This will produce output like so:

```
Changing password for pi.
(current) UNIX password:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

I was wondering if there is a possible way to change a password programmatically, like from a shell script.

I'm trying to make a configuration script to deploy on my Raspberry Pis and I don't want to manually have to type in new passwords for them.

Comment: To change the password of the current user you don't need to prefix with `sudo`. If you use `sudo` then you can force a new password for any user without needing to know that user's current password.

Comment: `expect(1)` could help as well.

Comment: Be sure to consider the security implications when programmatically changing passwords.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're looking for the `chpasswd` command. You'd do something like this:

```shell
echo 'pi:newpassword' | chpasswd # change user pi password to newpassword
```

Note that it needs to be run as root, at least with the default PAM configuration. But presumably run as root isn't a problem for a system deployment script.

Also, you can do multiple users at once by feeding it multiple lines of input.

Answer (score 16):

Another alternative is to use the `yes` command in your script.

```
yes newpassword | passwd youruser
```

This will send `newpassword` to the `passwd` command for `youruser`.

It should be mentioned that setting/modifying user passwords via scripts may present security risks and should be avoided whenever possible.

**EDIT:**

This answer requires root access.  Apologies for not mentioning this previously.  It is a method that I use when performing administration tasks which require root access.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes.  I have been using this method for years.  I tested it before posting my answer and again just now.

Comment: Even assuming that `passwd` read from `stdin` rather than a terminal (keyboard), how can this work when `passwd` prompts first for a user's old password and then prompts for the new?

Comment: @roaima possibly Timothy runs it as root (which would explain why he needs `youruser` at the end). It might work somewhere...

Comment: @roaima The `passwd` command from Linux's shadow utilities accepts redirected input (unlike e.g. OpenSSH `ssh`). Using `yes` is not a good idea though: it exposes the password to snoopers who look at the process list at the wrong time. Using `echo` would not have this defect because it's a shell builtin.

Comment: @Gilles so it does. @Timothy my apologies; I always understood that `passwd` read from /dev/tty rather than _stdin_. (Is that BSD behaviour?)

Comment: This one was actually the only of all these answers that worked in our application. We are on an embedded device running an ancient version of Busybox and none of the other programs used exist here.

Comment: This is not working on macOS 10.12.6 - apparently passwd is not reading from stdin. I'm looking for a solution to change the password programmatically on this system.

Answer (score 4):

The @derobert's answer is correct but I had to execute the command as superuser like this:

```
echo 'pi:newpassword' | sudo chpasswd # change user pi password to newpassword
```

Note the `sudo` after `|`. `sudo` at the start won't help you because it applies only to `echo`

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer!